# h:selectonemenu not firing change or valueChange event for the first time

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

facing a strange issue in one application I'm working on. This is a web-app using Richfaces 4.3. There is a `<h:selectOneMenu>` and inside that we are using a `<a4j:ajax>` element to fire a change event whenever the selected item is changed. Below is the code for this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu style="width:225px" id="mId" value="#{dataBean.meId }">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="-----Select----"></f:selectItem>           
<f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.mes}" />
<a4j:ajax listener="#{dataBean.findId }" event="change" execute="@form" render="mId">
</a4j:ajax> </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The issue is that when I am selecting the value from the list for the first time. it automatically deselects the value and returns me to the default "-----select-----" value and the listener method is not fired. I have tried running the app in eclipse debug mode and the break-point I placed on the starting of the method is not fired. When selecting for the 2nd time it fired the break-point and worked as expected.

Tried with the below approach also. but the result is the same for this also:

```
<h:selectOneMenu style="width:225px" id="mId" value="#{dataBean.meId } 
valueChangeListener="#{dataBean.findId1}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="-----Select----"></f:selectItem>
<f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.mes}" />
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@form" render="mId">
</a4j:ajax> </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Please suggest on the possible error reasons.

Comment: do you really need to submit the whole form when the selection is changed? if not, did you try using `execute="@this"`?